# Brackets editor CSS Class Code hint Plugin doesn't reconize the Bootstrap CSS CDN

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, class, brackets

we are making our template in Bootstrap 4 and using Bootstrap CSS CDN Link

but **Brackets CSS Class Code hint Plugin** is not recognizing the CSS form bootstrap CDN,

can anyone help me out how to figure out it  ?

Many thanks,

Comment: never used that particular extension, but generally things that are included outside of the local file system will give you some variety of error in whatever editor you are using (not just brackets)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
it's not giving any kind of error